# Explain the steps that follow for strtok

Tags: c, strtok

In the stackoverflow i found it that code, but i cant comment (yet) under the code for ask they explain me. I've so far searched this site but I haven't been able to figure out exactly what doing. After this code i using execvp. Can you explain me the logic of these steps and why?

```
char line[20];
char *program[20];
char **k = program;
char *t = strtok(line," \n");
while (t != NULL) {
    *k++ = t;
    t = strtok(NULL," \t");
}
*k = NULL;
```

Comment: Have you looked at the relevant documentation?

Comment: Seems to be separating words in `line` by spaces and tabs and storing their pointers in `program`. No bounds checking on program.

Comment: Where did you get this code? I don't know the purpose of `char **k = program; k++;*k = NULL;...`

Comment: @Barmak: It's filling in a NULL-terminated array of string pointers, which is what `execlp` expects as an argument. `k` points to the current position in the array.

Comment: Thanks @rici, I guess that was explained in earlier comment too, but I didn't get it at first.

Comment: @Alexander where do you mean?

Comment: @Mike I would start with a simple [google search](https://www.google.ca/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=strtok&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=ckn_WYXiF9CfXvX6pZAP), and go from there.